# Error "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute"

Tags: vb.net, operating-system

`Using frm as new FrmTest` 
`\\...Some Code Here`
`End Using`

Error "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute" when run "End Using" Code,

Anyone know what is the root cause for the error? 
and any solution for it?

Comment: There's nothing in what you have shown us that would explain the issue. What are you doing inside the `Using` block? Are you displaying that form as a modal dialogue? If not then you should not be using a `Using` block at all. Look at the exception details and it will tell you exactly where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Hi, Jmcihinney,The exception is throw during the `End Using` Code, ( I found it after i dubug with break point in one of my developed standard product. and the exception is " collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute”, The problem fixed after i change the command from Using  window.forms and End Using to Dim fm as Form, and it did happened on some PC but not the all, i am just curious to know the root cause, or i need to change all Code when i initial the form with Using .. End Using.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what a `Using` block actually does, so you should probably do some research into that.

Comment: Do you have a `For Each` loop that tries to change the items in a collection?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at what happens in `frmTest.Dispose`.